# GNOME Display Manager fails to load on startup

Tags: 12.10, gnome, gdm

I have installed gnome on my ubuntu 12.10. When i installed it, it initially worked fine for first two times but after that whenever i boot, it fails to start the display manager. The screen turns completely black. On pressing `esc` it gives a log of services being started. Its mentioned there

```
Starting GNOME display manager     [fail]
```

Then I use **tty1** and start gdm manually by

```
sudo gdm
```

I have re-installed gdm various times but its not helping.

I will be glad to provide any other information that is required.